# HSM9000 host command (NG/NH) to decrypt encrypted PIN

Tags: encryption

I need to get the Clear PIN for a card using HSM. I have used (EE/EF) command to get the encrypted PIN using PIN Offset method, and supplying its o/p to NG command to get the decrypted clear PIN value.

I am able to run both command and get the o/p however, Clear PIN value is incorrect.

Could I get some help here please.

Comment: I'd be surprised if an HSM would give you the clear PIN.

Comment: why not? NG command decrypts the encrypted value. Any other way to get the clear PIN out of HSM?

Comment: Because it’s effectively a verifying password. You only need to ask it “is 1234 the correct PIN, yes or no?” That way the HSM protects the real value so you the vendor can’t steal the PIN from an arbitrary card. You don’t need to know what the decrypted value is in normal use I don’t think.